# How could Jaylah hide this item?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-beyond

In Star Trek: Beyond, Jaylah has hidden the USS Franklin from Krall and his buddies using some sort of holo/light refraction cloaking technology.

How could this possibly work, as

> Krall and his buddies actually crash-landed that very ship themselves sometime earlier? Surely they remember where their ship crashed, and a ship doesn't just corrode away that quickly (evidently). 
>   
>  There is even a log recording of 'captain Krall' which seems to be recorded ON the ship AFTER it crashed, so it should be weird to them if the ship suddenly had disappeared.

So how could Jaylah hide the ship?

Comment: The obvious answer would be 'Because Abramsverse', but this would be not quite satisfying...

Comment: Related: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/57233/18237

Comment: Seems like Kraal would remember where he left his ship. Seems like he would head back for toilet paper every so often, too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My take on it was that Jaylah was hiding the USS Franklin not just to disguise its existence, but to disguise that she's spent hundreds of man-hours trying to put it back into into a flyable condition. This might include stuff that could be seen from the air (hull repairs and so forth).

Cloaking it would make it look like it had disappeared from view but rather than suspecting a cloak, anyone who was *previously aware* of its location would likely assume that the unstable ground, ***in which it was already partially buried***, had finally collapsed and hidden the rest of the ship.

Coupled with Krall's evident disinterest in the vessel and the 'traps' she set to discourage any casual investigations from the ground (either by Krall's men or any of the crews that he brought crashing down to the planet's surface) and it makes for a pretty good hiding place.

Comment: You may also want to mention that, without a GPS system or exact coordinates, it's fairly easy to lose something in a rough terrain/jungle environment.

Comment: @Omegacron - I'm acting on the assumption that Krall knows where it is (he's been on the planet for hundreds of years) so when it suddenly goes missing, he wouldn't immediately assume "cloak", he'd assume "landslide".