# Why is she safe in her hide-out?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-beyond

In Star Trek Beyond, the Enterprise crashes on a planet inhabited by a murderous faction. Also on this planet the woman Jaylah hides out from this faction. There are several moments in which the antagonists acknowledge knowing about her and even being irritated by her presence.

Jaylah hides out in

> what remains of the USS Franklin, a ship lost nearly 200 years earlier with all hands presumed dead. Her hideout is protected by traps and is obscured by some sort of hologram, rendering it invisible.

However, later we learn that

> the Franklin's Captain, Mr. Edison, has survived and is now known as Krall, the big bad evil guy. Obviously, he must know where he parked his ship, right?

So, how is it that Jaylah can hide here? Why is rendering her hideout invisible any kind of protection?

I've seen [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135348/how-could-jaylah-hide-this-item) but I feel this is sufficiently different. I'm not interested in why the antagonist ignored the hideout itself, but why he didn't go looking for Jaylah here.

Comment: I'm minded to dupe-close this. It sounds like you just don't like the answers on the other question.

Comment: Is there really any indication that the antagonists are irritated by her presence? I was under the impression she was hiding more from the other people stranded on the planet, not from Krall.

Comment: When Kirk gets ready to ... leave the planet and his ... vehicle appears to be holo-enhanced, Krall says to Manas (something like): "She's here, Find her!" - ie Jaylah's trademark combat style is immediately recognized and acted upon even while Kirk is creating a diversion.

Comment: @valorum "I've seen this question but I feel this is sufficiently different. I'm not interested in why the antagonist ignored the hideout itself, but why he didn't go looking for Jaylah here." How is that unclear? And why do you comment twice on dupe-closing this question even after I've linked to the possible duplicate myself and explained why I feel there;s a difference from the other question?

Comment: @steenbergh - Merely saying "I don't think this is a dupe" doesn't make it not a dupe. What finally pushed me over the edge was that it's not tagged Star-Trek which means my close vote isn't dupe-hammer binding.

Comment: The second comment is auto-added by SE when you mark something to close.

Comment: @Valorum we learn every day :-)